# Wordpress Delete hook with wp_delete_post function?

Tags: posts, hooks, customization

I have this action/hook:

```
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'my_delete_function' );
 function my_delete_function($post_id) { 
    global $wpdb;
    $achievement = get_the_category($post_id); 
    $h = $achievement[0]->cat_ID; 
    $s = ''.str_replace('"', '', $h);
   if ( $s == 6 || $s == 5){
        $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_votes WHERE post = ".$post_id) or die(mysql_error());

    }
}
```

The above works great when I am deleting posts from the admin. However, when the wp_delete_post() is called, the action doesnt work.

How can I make the action work with the delete function?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>`wp_delete_post()` **always** triggers `before_delete_post` - the problem must be that you're hooking your function conditionally (i.e. not all the time).</strike>

`before_delete_post` **only** gets triggered if you're actually *deleting* the post permanently, not just trashing it.

If you need to listen for trashing too, use `wp_trash_post`.

Answer (score 1):

Usage wp_delete_post:

```
wp_delete_post($postid, $force_delete = false)
```

'before_delete_post' hook is only called when post is force deleted. And not when it's just sent to trash. By default just

```
wp_delete_post($postid)
```

sends the post to trash. Because default $force_delete flag is false.
So, you have to force delete it by setting the flag to true:

```
wp_delete_post( $postid, true);
```