# How to hook a function only when I need to delete permanently a post?

Tags: posts, multisite, customization

I need to hook a function only when I delete permanently a post from the database, I've tried the 'before_delete_post' hook, however, it's called both when it's trashed and permanently deleted.

The wp_delete_post() function calls wp_trash_post() and should stop processing, but it looks like the wp_delete_post() is called again after the post is trashed.

I've seen this question: [Wordpress Delete hook with wp_delete_post function?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38244/wordpress-delete-hook-with-wp-delete-post-function). My need is exactly the oposite of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the "Sitewide tags" plugin which was misbehaving the natural WP flow. A function called `sitewide_tags_post_delete()` is hooked on 'trash_post' and it's calling `wp_delete_post()` to delete the post on the main blog.

Following the @Stephen's approach, I did this:

```
add_action('before_delete_post', 'my_deleted_post');
function my_deleted_post($post_id){
  global $blog_id;   
  if($blog_id == <main_blog_id>){ // usually is 1
    return false;
  }

  //do whatever you need :)
};
```

Answer (score 8):

`before_delete_post` is not called when a post is only trashed.

While `wp_delete_post()` can trash posts (if the post is not trashed and its not being forcibly deleted): it does so by calling `wp_trash_post()` and exiting the function prior to the triggering the action `before_delete_post`.

I've tested this, the following function will only 'die' when you permanently delete a post, but not when its confined to the trash. *The `wp_die` is to demonstrate when the call is being made - I do not recommend using it on a live site.*

```
add_action('before_delete_post', 'my_deleted_post');
function my_deleted_post($post_id){
   wp_die(var_dump($post_id));
};
```

The `wp_delete_post()` function can be found [here (WP 3.3.1)](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/post.php)

Comment: It should work, however, when it is used from the admin page, click in 'trash' within the post's list, the 'before_delete_post' is being called. I don't know why.

Comment: Do you mean the actions that appear in the table? I tried that, and trashing with the drop-down bulk actions. It worked for me. What version of WP are you using? Is it on a clean install as well? Some themes/plug-ins may be misbehaving.

Comment: I'm did exactly the same action as your example and it is being called when the post is trashed.

I'm using WP 3.2 and now checking whether another plugin could be screwing everything up.

Comment: BINGO! It is a WP multisite and I'm using the "Sitewide Tags" Plugin, it's deleting permanently the post from the main site, this is why 'before_delete_post' is being called!

Can I edit your answer and add 'Double check whether you have a clean instalation and another plugin is not hooked to "trash_post"'?

Sthephen, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Absolutely, glad you got it sorted.

Comment: @romulodl please add your solution as a separate answer (which is completely appropriate), instead of trying to edit it into this one

Comment: @Rarst: 

Stephen's answer is the correct one, what I added only complements it.

I didn't do any kind of different coding to fix it.

Comment: @romulodl the valuable info here is plugin that was causing the issue, which is totally worth separate answer. You can keep Stephen's as accepted or just upvote it and move accept to yours as precise solution - that's up to you. The point is that other people having same issue would see plugin at fault more prominently.

Comment: @Rarst Thanks for your help. I will answer myself (but I have to wait 8 hours), accept my own answer as correct and (try to) upvote Stephen's.